# Splitting an array of words into characters using a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, dictionary, split

So far, I have read a file (which is a poem)and split that poem so that each element of an array is each word of the poem(ex: ['Hey', 'diddle','diddle'...etc.]

Now I need to run through that array and input, for example, words[0] into a dictionary to create wordDict = {H:1,E:1,Y:1}. Each word is going to be evaluated to have the number of each letter as the key value depending on how many times it appears in the word (ex: apple =  wordDict = {a:1,p:2,l:1,e:1}).

```
wordDict = {};
for word in words:
    for letter in word:
        wordDict[letter] = 0 ; 
return wordDict;
```

Above is what I have so far but all this does is print every letter of the poem as the key and the key value = 0 (just to test). I also need for wordDict to be redefined everytime a new word is evaluated.

I tried to explain this as best as I could, but if you need clarification please comment to let me know.

Comment: For each letter check if `wordDict` already contains that letter. If not, create key and assign 1 to it, if it already exists, add 1 to it.

Comment: Do you want to keep a running count of the letters in each word, or do you want to discard the count every time, returning the last one?

Comment: I need the dictionary to first contain the first word, which is 'hey' and have the key be each letter and he key value be the number of time it appears in that word only. Then once that has been done, I need the array to take in the next word, and so on.

Comment: To build a new `Counter` for each word, you can do something like `for wordDict in map(Counter, words):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections
words = ['Hey', 'diddle', 'diddle']
[collections.Counter(word) for word in words]
# or list(map(collections.Counter, words))
```

Gives you:

```
[Counter({'H': 1, 'e': 1, 'y': 1}),
 Counter({'d': 3, 'e': 1, 'i': 1, 'l': 1}),
 Counter({'d': 3, 'e': 1, 'i': 1, 'l': 1})]
```

Comment: Does the "counter" have to be printed next to each dictionary? Is there a way to get rid of that or change it?

Comment: @Lucky'sCreations: `[dict(collections.Counter(word)) for word in words]`

Comment: Thanks! What is the code for accessing only the value in a dictionary? without having to put the key in the code and just accessing the value for comparison

Comment: @Lucky'sCreations: I don't know what you're asking, and this is not a chat platform, so please try to write the code yourself and if you're stuck, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
words = ['apple', 'banana']
allwordsList=[]
for word in words:
    wordDict = {};
    for letter in word:
        wordDict[letter] = 1 if letter not in wordDict else wordDict[letter] + 1; 
    allwordsList.append(wordDict)
print(allwordsList)
```

This would give you

```
[{'a': 1, 'p': 2, 'l': 1, 'e': 1}, 
 {'b': 1, 'a': 3, 'n': 2}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

words = ['Hey', 'diddle', 'diddle']

print(list(map(dict, map(collections.Counter, words))))
```

Which outputs:

```
[{'y': 1, 'e': 1, 'H': 1}, {'i': 1, 'l': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 3}, {'i': 1, 'l': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this without importing any module :

```
file1=['Hey', 'diddle','diddle']

track=0
for words in file1:
    result = {}

    for chara in words:
        if chara not in result:
            result[chara]=track
        else:
            result[chara]+=track

    print(result)
```

> output:

```
{'H': 0, 'y': 0, 'e': 0}
{'d': 0, 'i': 0, 'l': 0, 'e': 0}
{'d': 0, 'i': 0, 'l': 0, 'e': 0}
```